# How to Rename the existing Section name in Ini file?

Tags: c#, api, ini

Is there any way to rename the existing section name in the INI file
Ex.
    [section]
     field1="a"
     field2="b"
I wanna change the name "section" to "section1".
I am currently using "kernel32" APIs but seems those things use section name for reading.. Please help me on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bit obvious I know, but you will probably have to resort to copying the section under the new section name, then deleting the old section.